# `a` tag with runat server and tilde in href

Tags: asp.net

For example, I have two sibling pages `Index.aspx` and `Orders.aspx` in one folder. On the page `Index.aspx` I have the link to `Orders.aspx`. What is the correct way to implement this:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Orders.aspx">
```

or

```
<a href="Orders.aspx">
```

I know what `runat="server"` does (server-control, performance impact etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really never need to run markup with a run at server tag if it's never used in code behind, if it is then you should use a ASP.NET control for it.

So just a hyperlink without `runat=server` would be fine.

It's always best to use ASP.NET controls on your page though if an upgrade in the future could require language translations, or have some logic assigned to them in the future. So always plan ahead on your designs.

Answer (score 1):

If both views are in the same folder, than the second one:

```
<a href="Orders.aspx">
```